# Erro Android SDK could not be found

Tags: android, xamarin, sdk

Após clicar no arquivo `Main.xml` apareceu este erro:

> Erro Android SDK could not be found.

Como posso corrigir isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema com a resposta? Ou precisa de mais alguma informação?

Answer (score 2):

Faça o download do [**SDK do Android**](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) a partir do site oficial.  Em seguida, abra o gerenciador de **SDK** e baixe os suplementos necessários. Depois disso  selecione o local **SDK** nas preferências dos **Xamarin**.

Comment: A imagem talvez não ajude muito ele está usando `Visual Studio`